# How to remove unwanted program installed in error

Tags: uninstall

I recently downloaded xsane and as a third party it is blocking updates to my 16.04lts. How to remove? i've tried various combinations on terminal, all to no effect.

Comment: xsane should not be blocking updates. Please [edit] the output of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: You have to tell is which commands or method you used to install the program. It is best to edit the question above and add new information.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it using `apt` or `apt-get` you can remove it with `sudo apt remove xsane` or `sudo apt purge xsane`. The latter removes configuration files as well.

Comment: The first word **if** is the most important part. If not, then what?

Comment: How did you install xsane then? Please edit your question.